# Django - REMOTE_HOST empty answer

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am having problem with empty answer, code is here:

views.py

```
def home(request):
    ime = request.META['REMOTE_HOST']
    return HttpResponse('Welcome, %s.' %ime)
```

and I am getting:

```
Welcome, .
```

for answer. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: There isn't really a problem, the header just isn't set. You may be looking for `REMOTE_ADDR` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In my project I also meet this problem.

But I used socket method to get client host to solve this issue, detail as below:

```
def welcome(request):
    try:
        real_ip = request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
        regip = real_ip.split(",")[0]
    except:
        try:
            regip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        except:
            regip = ""
    print(regip)
    if(regip == "127.0.0.1"):
        myHost=socket.gethostname()
    else:
        resultHost = socket.gethostbyaddr(regip)
        myHost=resultHost[0]
    print(myHost)
```

Comment: This is very hard to read when you don't format your code properly

Answer (score 1):

`REMOTE_HOST` header is not mandatory. Try printing your `request.META` dictionary to see actually what's being passed on the HTTP headers. Or you can use a browser in development mode to see that.